# Use Adobe LiveCycle Form to Fill in Data in a Large PDF

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe, livecycle

Is it possible to use a LiveCycle form to gather data and export the data into various locations in a PDF? If so, how can I do this? If there's any other way to do it, I am up for that too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear to me. Are you talking about a mechanism to store various data elements within a LiveCycle form and populating the stored data in dropdowns etc ? It will help a bit if you can explain the use case you are trying to meet.